# Aligning navbar text to the right with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a google clone but I can't get li's to the very right of the page with Bootstrap 4, this link contains the code that I'm trying to edit, I tried to add `mr-auto` and `justify-content-end` to the `ul` but still, nothing works.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzvforjk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the items to the very right, you can use

```
.navbar-nav {
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

The `ul` is set with `flex-direction: column;`, which means that you have to use `align-items` to position items horizontally and `justify-content` to position items vertically.

Try this snippet:

```css
.navbar-nav {
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white ">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gmail</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Images</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Circle
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!--Bootstrap Scripts;-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

If you want everything to the very right of the page (the hamburger icon and the items), you can do this:

```
.navbar-nav {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

nav.navbar {
   justify-content: flex-end;
}

.dropdown.show, .dropdown-menu.show {
  text-align: right;  
}
```

Since `nav.navbar` has the default `flex-direction: row`, `justify-content` positions content horizontally and `align-items` positions content vertically for `nav.navbar`.

I set `text-align: right;` on the list item dropdown so that it stays aligned to the right when it is opened.

Try this snippet below:

```css
.navbar-nav {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

nav.navbar {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.dropdown.show, .dropdown-menu.show {
  text-align: right;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white ">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gmail</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Images</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Circle
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<!--Bootstrap Scripts;-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Update**

This snippet will make sure everything is aligned to the right on **all screen widths**. I removed `mr-auto` from the html since it interfered with flexbox's ability to justify the content to the end of the flex container.

```css
.navbar-nav {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

nav.navbar {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.dropdown.show,
.dropdown-menu.show {
  text-align: right;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .dropdown-menu.show {
    left: -8rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Google.css">

<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white ">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gmail</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Images</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Circle
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!--Bootstrap Scripts;-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The hamburger to the right works but aligning the items itself still won't work,  I'm confused.

Comment: Hmm - in the second snippet everything is aligned to the right. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: yes but also, I wanted to set the li's in the ul to the very right of the navbar so the text will appear on the right when the browser is in the pc full screen.

Comment: Oh whoops ok I'll fix that.

Comment: @CEALOA I added another snippet at the bottom that will work on desktop views as well.

Comment: Thanks very much everything works perfectly now!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it helped :) Sorry I forgot about the desktop view initially.